# how to get data from API, when data of API as map<dynamic , dynamic>. if data as DoctorModel inside it daysModel, inside daysModel is workTimeModel

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dart-pub

I want to get data from API, my API data as DoctorModel inside it daysModel, inside daysModel is workTimeModel, each doctor has many days and has worktime.

I tried a lot of ways but still can't fix it.

note: I made my API from this website https://app.quicktype.io/

my code to get API data:

```
Response res = await get(
      doctorsUrl ,
    );
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
      List<dynamic> data = body['data'];
      List<DoctorInfoModel> doctors =  data.map((dynamic item) => DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return doctors;
    }
```

my API:

```
{
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Prof. Elton Quigley",
        "about": "uHiKeKA1gq",
        "stars": 5,
        "location": "R59lmj1eud",
        "latitude": 5,
        "longitude": 5,
        "notes": "yCl95VqUAz",
        "days": [
            {
                "name": "سبت",
                "pivot": {
                    "doctor_id": 15,
                    "day_id": 1,
                    "morning": "1",
                    "evening": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "أحد",
                "pivot": {
                    "doctor_id": 15,
                    "day_id": 2,
                    "morning": "3",
                    "evening": "3"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "إثنين",
                "pivot": {
                    "doctor_id": 15,
                    "day_id": 3,
                    "morning": "5",
                    "evening": "5"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ثلاثاء",
                "pivot": {
                    "doctor_id": 15,
                    "day_id": 4,
                    "morning": "4",
                    "evening": "4"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "أربعاء",
                "pivot": {
                    "doctor_id": 15,
                    "day_id": 5,
                    "morning": "5",
                    "evening": "5"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "خميس",
                "pivot": {
                    "doctor_id": 15,
                    "day_id": 6,
                    "morning": "4",
                    "evening": "4"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

my DoctorModel:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final doctorInfoModel = doctorInfoModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

DoctorInfoModel doctorInfoModelFromJson(String str) => DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String doctorInfoModelToJson(DoctorInfoModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DoctorInfoModel {
    DoctorInfoModel({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.about,
        this.stars,
        this.location,
        this.latitude,
        this.longitude,
        this.notes,
        this.days,
    });

    int id;
    String name;
    String about;
    int stars;
    String location;
    int latitude;
    int longitude;
    String notes;
    List<Day> days;

    factory DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DoctorInfoModel(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        about: json["about"],
        stars: json["stars"],
        location: json["location"],
        latitude: json["latitude"],
        longitude: json["longitude"],
        notes: json["notes"],
        days: List<Day>.from(json["days"].map((x) => Day.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "about": about,
        "stars": stars,
        "location": location,
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
        "notes": notes,
        "days": List<dynamic>.from(days.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Day {
    Day({
        this.name,
        this.pivot,
    });

    String name;
    Pivot pivot;

    factory Day.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Day(
        name: json["name"],
        pivot: Pivot.fromJson(json["pivot"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "pivot": pivot.toJson(),
    };
}

class Pivot {
    Pivot({
        this.doctorId,
        this.dayId,
        this.morning,
        this.evening,
    });

    int doctorId;
    int dayId;
    String morning;
    String evening;

    factory Pivot.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Pivot(
        doctorId: json["doctor_id"],
        dayId: json["day_id"],
        morning: json["morning"],
        evening: json["evening"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "doctor_id": doctorId,
        "day_id": dayId,
        "morning": morning,
        "evening": evening,
    };
}
```

**How can I get data correctly?**

Comment: `var res  = DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(res.body);`

Comment: @JohnJoe thanks for your answer, but i got this error when using your code: `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.`

Comment: how about `DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));` ?

Comment: You can automate this twice. Here is a link to the next step: https://github.com/mezoni/rpc_gen. Look at the description for how you can do this (it's simple). You do not have to think too much about how to do it properly. Because everything will work automatically.

Comment: @JohnJoe got this error : `[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get data.

I replaced these two lines:

```
List<dynamic> data = body['data'];
List<DoctorInfoModel> doctors =  data.map((dynamic item) => DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

by these:

```
var data = body['data'];
DoctorInfoModel doctorInfo = DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(data);
```

when my `DoctorInfoModel` is not a `List`, so I delete it.

**Correct code to get API data:**

```
 if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
      var data = body['data'];
      DoctorInfoModel doctorInfo = DoctorInfoModel.fromJson(data);
      print(doctorInfo.name);
      print(doctorInfo.about);
      print(doctorInfo.days[0].name);
      print(doctorInfo.days[0].pivot.morning);
      return doctorInfo;
    }
```